# Symfony 3 VichUploaderBundle not moving images to the correct directory

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I am attempting to use The VichImageBundle with Symfony3, there is no documentation as of yet for the FormType::class call that is new to S3 in conjunction with the Vich Image Bundle. I have everything working except for the moving part.

I have made a folder structure here inside the project here: web/images/aod_images

I have set the configuration in the yml file like this:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm 

    mappings:      
        aod_images:
            uri_prefix:         /images/aod_images
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/aod_images
```

The entity properties are here: (I have the getters and setters in place)

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="aod_images", fileNameProperty="dailyChartName")
 * 
 * @var File
 */
private $dailyChart;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * 
 * @var string
 */
private $dailyChartName;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="aod_images", fileNameProperty="twohourChartName")
 * 
 * @var File
 */
private $twohourChart;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * 
 * @var string
 */
private $twohourChartName;
```

I am calling a set time method as appropriate in the controller class, specifically on the editAction and the newAction controllers:

```
$analysis->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
```

In the FormType class for this entity I have the following so far:

```
->add('dailyChartName', FileType::class, array())
->add('twohourChartName', FileType::class, array())
```

I'm not sure what options to pass to the ->add method yet for each image instance.

The application is building the forms correctly.

When I do a tail -f the dev.log I get the following message as part of the doctrine.DEBUG channel:

```
(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\UploadedFile: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpEz6kJO)","13":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\UploadedFile: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpVkbZgi)
```

The image name property does not match what I have mapped in the config.yml file. Instead the path reflects my local machines route to internal php tmp directory. I'm running this from 127.0.0.1:8000 after using the server:run command.

When I look in that directory the image has **NOT** been moved there.

The (incorrect)image name is being copied to the database. However the path to the image is empty (incorrect path). In addition the correct path/directory is also empty.

Regards!

**EDIT**

As per suggestion by Matteo I have made the following change to the FormType.php file.

```
->add('dailyChart', VichFileType::class, array(
            'required' => TRUE,
        ))
->add('twohourChart', VichFileType::class, array(
            'required' => TRUE,            
        ))
```

**EDIT 2**

In an attempt to make my implementation to adhere more closely to the documentation I put my updatedAt set inside the entity as per docs suggestion.

My set methods look something like this:

```
public function setDailyChart(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $dailyChart)
{
    $this->dailyChart = $dailyChart;
        if ($dailyChart) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    return $this;
}
```

I explicitly set typehinting with a full path. Now I receive the following error.

```
AppBundle\Entity\MTI_Cart\AodTechnicalAnalysis::setDailyChart() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File given
```

Comment: check if you correctly annotate your class with the `Uploadable` annotation as described [here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#step-2-link-the-upload-mapping-to-an-entity). I think you do, is only a check

Comment: yes I made sure of that... @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="aod_images", fileNameProperty="twohourChartName"). I took that part of it directly from the page that you linked to. I just double checked that my mappings here on the entity matched that in the config file. It matches perfectly.

Comment: /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use this bundle with symfony3 you must use the form type: `VichFileType` as described in the doc [here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/form/vich_file_type.md), as example:

```
// ...
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

// ...

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('image', VichFileType::class, array(
        'required'      => false,
        'allow_delete'  => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
    ));
}
```

So try this in your formType class:

```
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;
//..
->add('dailyChartName', VichFileType::class, array())
->add('twohourChartName', VichFileType::class, array())
```

Hope this help

Comment: I made all changes as you and the documentation suggested. Switched to VichFileType::class and brought in the appropriate USE statement. I also enabled the vich form theme as the documentation you linked to suggests. I still get the same behavior. Still the same doctrine message in the log file with the path of the image saved. In the wrong place. And when I look in the directory, the image didn't actually get moved().

Comment: I added the updateAt code to the setter methods and added type hinting as per suggestion by the docs, now I get a type error. I've made not of it via an edit in my OP

Comment: hi @RickMason i see  your update. In the [usage](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md) guide the method of the file is a simple File instead of UploadedFile as your setter.

Comment: Thanks @matteo for your help in working me through this issue. Turns out I did not have the File, Name and their appropriate classes EXACTLY right.